# Weird spacing in my HTML that only appears in Chrome and not in IE or Komodo Edit's Preview

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I wrote this in jsfiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/s2cq61ko/

Below is the HTML.

```
<div id="wrapper">
 <h2>I am a generalist</h2>

<div id="Boxy">
    <div id="GeneralistHeader">Stratgey & Design</div>
    <div id="General_List">
        <ul>
            <li class="Big">systems theory</li>
            <li class="Medium">branding</li>
            <li class="Small">ethnography</li>
            <li class="Small">statistics</li>
            <li class="Big">iOS development</li>
            <li class="Medium">user experience</li>
            <li class="Small">web development</li>
            <li class="Small">infographics</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
 <h2>Here are past projects</h2>

<p>that will let you see my thought process.</p>
</div>
```

Then this is the CSS...

```
#wrapper {
    max-width: 940px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 5%;
    text-align: center;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none
}

#GeneralistHeader {
    font-size:2em;
    font-weight: 700;
    background:#19334c;
    color:white;
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 2px 10px;
    margin: -20px 0 0 0;
}
#Boxy {
    border: solid;
    display:inline-block;
    border-width: 1px;
    margin-top: 35px;
    width:500px
}
#General_List ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    /*number of columns*/
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    /* Firefox */
    column-count: 2;
    margin: 10px 0 0 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family:'Raleway', serif;
    font-weight: 400;
}
```

Notice the massive spacing after the box. It doesn't appear in IE or Komodo Edit's Preview. But when I open it on Chrome, it shows up like that...

I'm sure it's the CSS, but I could not figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution is to change #Boxy to this:

```
#Boxy {
    border: solid;
    display: block;      /* from inline-block to block */
    border-width: 1px;
    margin-top: 35px;
    margin-left: auto;   /* added this line */
    margin-right: auto;  /* added this line */
    width: 500px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things going on here. One is that using inline-block can produce odd spacing. If you adjust to using display block and then apply a margin-left auto and margin-right auto you will still center your box. The second thing I noticed is that you have applied a margin top of 1.75em to h2's. If you change this declaration to a class and only target the h2 that you intend to have the margin adjust then that gap goes away.

Comment: evilrobotz, I understood the part about display block. I fixed it accordingly. But can you elaborate on the class h2? I did it on my komodo edit code but it doesn't seem like anything changed... I changed wrapper id to wrapper class. Then I changed h2 {} to .wrapper h2 {}.. What does this do for me? Thanks btw!

Comment: you have two h2's in your code. I would tag on with a class or id and attach the margin to that one. The other one that is lower in the code will inherit your current margin due to also being an h2 in the .wrapper unless you make your h2 specific.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this [link](https://jsfiddle.net/s2cq61ko/15/)

```
enter code here
```

You should make the Boxy on display and use margin: 0 auto; for positioning your box.